# spring Functional binding names multiple inputs to one output in spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

How to set multiple input channels to output to the same destanation

I have the following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: beer;scotch
      bindings:
        notification:
          destination: labron
        beer-in-0:
          destination: wheat
        scotch-in-0:
          destination: wiskey
```

I want to create Function binding so that each input channel will output it's message to  notification binding

So in the corresponding code:

```
@Service
class Notifications {
  @Bean
  fun beer(): Function<String, String> = Function {
    // wanted oout channel
    // beer -> notification
    it.toUpperCase()
  }

  @Bean
  fun scotch(): Function<String, String> = Function {
    // wanted oout channel
    // scotch -> notification
    it.toUpperCase()
  }
```

}

I want to use Spring Cloud Stream 3.0 functional binding names.

```
beer -> notification
scotch -> notification
```

What is the best way to active that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest going with something like so (based on [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functions_with_multiple_input_and_output_arguments)):

```
    @Bean
    public Function<Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>, Flux<String>> beerAndScotch() {
        return tuple -> {
            Flux<String> beerStream = tuple.getT1().map(item -> item.toUpperCase());
            Flux<String> scotchStream = tuple.getT2().map(item -> item.toUpperCase());
            return Flux.merge(beerStream, scotchStream);
        };
    }
```

and so your definition should look something like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: beerAndScotch
      bindings:
        notification:
          destination: labron
        beerAndScotch-in-0:
          // ...
        beerAndScotch-in-1:
          // ...
        beerAndScotch-out-0:
          destination: labron
```

This way, both inputs to `beer` and inputs to `scotch` get sent to `labron`

Comment: +1 to @orirab. Just wanted to add few things. If you don't want to go reactive approach you can still do it with your original setup. All you need is to map output bindings of functions to the same destination via `...function.bindings...` property. For example, `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.scotch-out-0=notification` and `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.beer-out-0=notification`. For more on this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names)